# missing redis library when redis is installed

Tags: python, redis, pycharm, celery, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have redis and celery python libraries installed. I have redis server installed and running. using bash i can run `python` and `import redis` without errors. I have python-celery-common installed. I am using PyCharm and WSL. For some reason when i create tasks.py and try to run `celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info`
 in bash i get the following stack trace (note the python3 in the path to celery when i am running python 2.7 - i have a feeling this is important but not sure how, or how to change):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/celery", line 26, in <module>
    load_entry_point("celery", "console_scripts", "celery")()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 14, in main
    _main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 326, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 488, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 281, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 480, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 412, in execute
    ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 221, in run_from_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 244, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 255, in run
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 99, in __init__
    self.setup_instance(**self.prepare_args(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 122, in setup_instance
    self.should_use_eventloop() if use_eventloop is None
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 241, in should_use_eventloop
    self._conninfo.transport.implements.async and
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 832, in transport
    self._transport = self.create_transport()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 576, in create_transport
    return self.get_transport_cls()(client=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 1009, in __init__
    raise ImportError('Missing redis library (pip install redis)')
ImportError: Missing redis library (pip install redis)
```

output from bash when i run `python`:

```
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

output from `pip freeze`

```
 amqp==2.3.2
asn1crypto==0.24.0
billiard==3.5.0.5
celery==4.2.1
cryptography==2.1.4
Django==1.11.11
djangorestframework==3.9.0
enum34==1.1.6
idna==2.6
ipaddress==1.0.17
keyring==10.6.0
keyrings.alt==3.0
kombu==4.2.2
psycopg2==2.7.4
pycrypto==2.6.1
pygobject==3.26.1
pytz==2018.7
pyxdg==0.25
redis==3.0.1
SecretStorage==2.3.1
six==1.11.0
sqlparse==0.2.4
vine==1.1.4
```

Comment: why don't you use virtual environment to avoid such issues? looks like you need to change the default python version in your OS (if you still want to use it globally)

Comment: you should restart app

Answer (score 0):

The more plausible problem is that in pycharm when you set up the interpreter you gave it the wrong path.You set it to /usr/bin/python3 instead of the path to python2